# is the group cyclic, if Normal Subgroup and Quotient group are cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Prove or disprove that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ such that $H$ and $\frac{G}{H}$ are cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

I am not sure if the above question has any mistake.

I know examples where $\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic, but $G$ is not cyclic. It is
$$G = S_3 = \{ I, (12),(23),(31), (123), (132) \}$$
and $$H = \{I,(123),(132)\}$$ H is a normal subgroup of G. 
$\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic since order of G/H is 2 and every group of prime order is cyclic.

But G is not cyclic.

I am doing graduation course.

Please give me an example to disprove or proof for above problem.

Comment: The question asks "prove or disprove," and it seems like you disproved it with a valid counterexample.

Comment: @angryavian, The example I gave is when only $\frac{G}{H}$ is cyclic. But the question asks when both $H$ and $\frac{G}{H}$ are cyclic.

Comment: @Tortoise But your $H$ is indeed  Cyclic, because it has prime order, too!

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Thank you,  I missed it. Then my example would suffice the question to disprove it.

Answer (score 0):

As a counter-example, you can take $G = C_2\times C_2$.