# Prove or disprove: If $H$ and $G/H$ are cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I tried to prove it by proving that if $\frac GH$ is cyclic, there is $gH$ such that $(gH)^n=e_{(G/H)}=e_{(G)}*H$. Since $(gH)^n=g^nH$, $g^n=e_G$. So $G$ is cyclic.

I don't think it's correct since I didn't use the condition that $H$ is cyclic but I couldn't figure what's wrong. Would be great if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong and maybe point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The non-cyclic group of order $4$ tends to be a good place to start looking for examples.

Comment: Very stupid counterexample for your proof: Take any non-cyclic group $G$ and look at $G/G$.

Comment: @Verdruss  I don't think that is a counterexample.  The OP requires $H$ to be cyclic.

Comment: @lulu: Not a counterexample for the statement, but since he was unsure if his proof was correct and he didn't use that $H$ is cyclic, it is just a "counterexample" for his proof.

Comment: @Verdruss Qh, good point.  The OP does appear to be arguing that $G/H$ cyclic implies $G$ is cyclic, and for that your counterexample works beautifully.

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488760/is-the-group-cyclic-if-normal-subgroup-and-quotient-group-are-cyclic?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: For the counterexample, wouldn't $G/G=gG=G$ since $g\in G$? So if $G/G $is cyclic, $G$ would have to be cyclic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot conclude that $g^n=e_G$, only that $g^n\in H$.

Secondly, and more importantly, the (false) conclusion that $g^n=e_G$ has absolutely nothing to do with $G$ being cyclic (or not).

To prove that $G$ is cyclic, you would need to find an element $g\in G$ such that $g^n$ is *not* $e_G$ for $0<n<\lvert G\rvert$ (assuming that $G$ is finite).

In any case, this is not true. To find a counterexample, take a nontrivial cyclic $H$ and $G=H\times H$.

Answer (score 3):

Take the Klein four-group $V=\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$, which is not cyclic. Take any of its three subgroups of order $2$ (therefore cyclic), then their quotient will also be of order $2$ (therefore cyclic).